# RequireJS, Shim, dependencies not properly loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've been working on a project that has more front end scripting than I'm used to, and I decided to use RequireJS to keep it organized. After mucking around all night, I'm still having some issues where certain dependencies seem to load after the fact.

For instance, Sammy needs jQuery to work. Refreshing my app results in a 'Sammy, function undefined' sort of error. Is the Require function executing before jQuery is loaded?

**Require config:**

```
    require.config({
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'vendor/jquery.2.min',
            'sammy': 'vendor/sammy',
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery': {
                debs: [],
                exports: '$'
            },
            'sammy': {
                debs: ['jquery'],
                exports: 'Sammy'
            }
            ...
```

As for my navigation:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'sammy'
], function($, Sammy) {

    return Sammy(function() {
    ...
```

In about 10 percent of my tests, upon hitting the Sammy function, the app poops out with the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined sammy.js:2120
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The RequireJS way of working mystifies me. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `debs: ['jquery']` a typo? Should be `deps`
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Comment: You can also use the require-jquery.js, which has jQuery included and will always load it before anything else: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: 'organised' wasn't a typo. Leave en_GB alone! ;)

Comment: Sometimes you really need a second pair of eyes... Why not post it as an answer? I'll accept it if works

Comment: @Paul Grime en_AU ;-)

Comment: Done, hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a typo in your configuration, the correct property name would be `deps` instead of `debs` as specified in the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).

```
'jquery': {
    deps: [],
    exports: '$'
},
'sammy': {
    deps: ['jquery'],
    exports: 'Sammy'
}
```